# A nice way to visualize fixed points of coupled diff eq system

Tags: differential-equations, visualization

I deal with the Riccati equation for complex function `z[t]`,

```
   D[z[t], t]==A+B[z]*z[t]+C[z]*Abs[z[t]]^2,
```

where `B[z]` and `C[z]` are known functions of `z` and `A` is a constant. Representing `z[t]=r[t]*Exp[I*f[t]]`, I rewrite this system as a system of two coupled differential equations. My interestes turn around fixed points, their existence and stability. I have performed all the calculations by hand and now would like to visualize them and test my ideas. So, my questions are:

- Does a function in Mathematica (or in Wolfram Function repository) that allow to simply visualize fixed points of diff eq? I have tried `StreamPlot`, `ContourPlot` and `ParametricPlot` but my results are not nice and clear
- Does  `DSolve` and `NDSolve` can deal with complex functions? So, is it possible to solve the equation as is?

Comment: A fix point is a point where the vector (velocity) field is zero. Therefore, "VectorPlot" will visualize these points. DSolve and NDSolve deal by default with complex function

Comment: It is good that you have already tried  `StreamPlot`, `ContourPlot` and `ParametricPlot`.  This would be a good starting point for answering your question. Please add the code to your post and describe what exactly was not nice and clear. Most probably you will need a numerical solver `NDSolve`. It can deal with complex functions.

Comment: Thanks for yours comments, they are both useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not wrong, what you want may be a flow like:

```
a = 1;
b[z_] = z;
c[z_] = I - z;

rhs = a + b[z] z + c[z] Abs[z]^2;

(* stream plot of {r'[t], f'[t]} in the r-f plane *)
StreamPlot[
  {Re[rhs / z] r, Im[rhs / z]} /. z -> r E^(I f),
  {r, 0, 5},
  {f, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image]

You can check this flow diagram by numerically solving the equation. For example, the plot of a solution starting from $z(0)=2 e^{3i}$ in the the $r$-$f$ plane can be obtained as

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {z'[t] == (rhs /. z -> z[t]), z[0] == z0}, z, {t, 0, 10}, {z0}
];
Block[{z0 = 2 Exp[3 I]},
  ParametricPlot[
    {Abs[sol[z0][t]], Arg[sol[z0][t]]},
    {t, 0, 10},
    PlotRange -> All
  ]
]
```

[image]

which goes to the fixed point at $(r, f) = (1, \pi/2)$.

Comment: But why you divdided Re and Im parts of RHS by `z` and then multiplied by `r` only Re part?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov Because the LHS is $z' = (r' / r + i f') z$ and so you can get $r'$ and $f'$ in this way for real $r$ and $f$.